# Игра не правильно работает после компиляции на PC

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что в Unity игра работает корректно, а после компиляции забагалась. Как это проявляется: Светящиеся цилиндры должны загораться последовательно друг за другом, после проезда по ним. Изначально горит первый цилиндр, а остальные не горят. После проезда по первому он гаснет, загорается второй и тд **(скрин 1 и 2)**. А в итоге после компиляции: Сначала загорается 7 цилиндр, потом 1, потом 8 и тд **(скрин 3)**. Чем это может быть вызвано? И как пофиксить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код цилиндров:

```
void Start()
    {
        i = 1;
        way = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Point");
        for (int n = 1; n < way.Length; n++)
        {
            way[n].SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    public void Fun()
    {
        //удаление прошлой точки
        {
            way[i-1].SetActive(false);
        }
        i++;
        if (i == 9)
        {
            Application.Quit();
        } else
        {
            Score.text = (i - 1).ToString();
            way[i - 1].SetActive(true);
        }       
    }
```

Вот скриншот иерархии точек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, код который активирует цилиндры

Comment: @Andrey , добавил код.

Comment: попробуйте прилепить к каждому цилиндру индекс.  И сортируйте по индексам и уже с отсортированным работайте. И никаких проблем не будет

Comment: @Andrey , у меня же и так каждый цилиндр под каким-то индексом в массиве way. Или вы что-то другое имеете ввиду?

Comment: вы берете все цилиндры через FindObjectsWithTag. И идете уже по их иерархии. А там они могут идти не в том порядке что вам нужен. А если вы явно укажете что этот цилиндр первый, а этот второй, возьмете все цилиндры и отсортируете по вот этим вот индексам что вы вручную задали тогда все должно быть хорошо

Comment: @Andrey , добавил скриншот иерархии точек. В Unity они у меня расположены так как мне и нужно ( 1-2-3-n-9). Не понимаю путь реализации вашей идеи и её отличие от текущей ситуации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при запуске игры в Unity объекты работают по той иерархии, которая указана в проекте. Но после компиляции Эта иерархия может быть  нарушена (как в моем примере: вместо Point1-2-3-...-9 у меня было вразброс Point6-1-7-2-3-9.. и тд.) 
 Мне помогло использование List<> вместо массива и сортировки по имени.

```
public List<GameObject> Points;
Points = new List<GameObject>();
Points = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Point").ToList();
Points = Points.OrderBy(go => go.name).ToList();
```

Всем удачи!